# How to document **kwargs in python?

Tags: python, functions, parameters, definition

I have a function which has a large number of arguments.

I want to have the names of the arguments available in the help() function, but I want the results as a dict.

At the moment, I have the following:

```
def myfunc(thisparameter,thatparameter,hostname,password,port,service,url,someotherparameter, etc, andsoforth):
   return some_function(dict(thisparameter=thisparameter,thatparameter=thatparameter,hostname=hostname,port=port,service=service,url=url,someotherparameter=someotherparameter, etc=etc, andsoforth=andsoforth))
```

I can't just use kwargs, since that means the help() function won't show the parameters. I have a lot of these. I understand that I can use `__doc__`, but that still shows the parameters as **kwargs.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not document the actual parameters? The function doesn't appear to be using kwargs at all, so why would you want to document kwargs?

Comment: For clarification, I was asking exactly what @Tibo answered. I wanted it to be documented as if there was no kwargs, but to get the parameters in a dict. locals() is the (a?) correct method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) hack [proposed in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521901/get-a-list-tuple-dict-of-the-arguments-passed-to-a-function), like so:

```
def myfunc(thisparameter,thatparameter):
  return some_function(**locals())
```

This allows you to explicit arguments to `myfunc` and call your implementation without the need to repeat all the arguments.

It is not bulletproof. For a more "secure" version you might want to use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

(As a side note, I'm flagging this question for migration to SO. I'm however not so sure if this is a duplicate as you have the help twist that is not mentioned in the SO question)

Comment: This is almost exactly the answer I was looking for - minus the `**`, so some_function gets a dict.